# Unable to download Desktop App Converter from Windows 10 Store

Tags: windows-store-apps, parallels, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

Downloaded and loaded Windows 10 Pro (X64) via Parallels Desktop and attempted to download Desktop App Converter but wasn't able to do so as I was receiving a message stating "This app will not work on your device."

On scrolling down I could see that the issue was caused due to the fact that the Store did not detect that my OS was running in X64 architecture, but it was ! (as seen in the screenshot)
[image: DesktopAppConverter_Message]
[image: DesktopAppConverter_Windows10Store_Error]

Comment: I will report this issue to related team to have an investigation. The process might take some time delay. Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Microsoft support team, explaining this. A tech representative took control of my desktop and figured out that the issue was that I was running Windows 10 as a VM on a Mac.

The work around is to install the Desktop App Converter from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51691

Comment: That version of DAC is quite old and unsupported so it may get you unblocked. As that's several release back, it has been unpublished now.

Comment: @MattewWu-MSFT - Yes, I guess you're right, the link I had provided doesn't open anymore. I'm going to dual boot my Mac in Windows 10, instead of running it in a VM. Let's see if that works.